# Navigating inside a tab in TabbedPage in MvvmCross

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross

I am building an app using MvvmCross and using a MvxScaffolding template. The app should start like this:

```
|-------------------------|
|           Tab1          |
|                         |
|                         |
|        |--------|       |
|        | Button |       |
|        |--------|       |
|                         |
|                         |
|-------------------------|
|    Tab1    |    Tab2    |
|-------------------------|
```

And when I click on the button in the `Tab1Page` it should navigate to a `Tab1ChildPage` like this:

```
|-------------------------|
| <Back  Tab1Child        |
|                         |
|                         |
|                         |
|                         |
|                         |
|                         |
|                         |
|-------------------------|
|    Tab1    |    Tab2    |
|-------------------------|
```

However when I click on the button the `Tab1ChildPage` is getting added to the tabs instead:

```
|-------------------------|
|           Tab1          |
|                         |
|                         |
|        |--------|       |
|        | Button |       |
|        |--------|       |
|                         |
|                         |
|-------------------------|
| Tab1 | Tab2 | Tab1Child |
|-------------------------|
```

This is how I am doing it:

On `HomePageViewModel` I add the two tab pages:

```
public override void ViewAppearing()
{
    if (_firstTime)
    {
        ShowInitialViewModels();
        _firstTime = false;
    }
}

private Task ShowInitialViewModels()
{
    var tasks = new List<Task>
    {
        _navigationService.Navigate<Tab1ViewModel>(),
        _navigationService.Navigate<Tab2ViewModel>()
    };
    return Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

And in `Tab1ViewModel` I call the navigation when a button is clicked:

```
public ICommand ButtonCommand => new MvxCommand(() => { _navigationService.Navigate<Tab1ChildViewModel>(); });
```

What I am doing wrong?

---

EDIT (2021-04-19T14:07). Responding to comments:

I have the following presentation attributes on my pages:

HomePage.xaml.cs:

```
[MvxTabbedPagePresentation(TabbedPosition.Root)]
public partial class HomePage : MvxTabbedPage<HomeViewModel>
```

Tab1Page.xaml.cs:

```
[MvxTabbedPagePresentation(TabbedPosition.Tab)]
public partial class Tab1Page : MvxContentPage<Tab1ViewModel>
```

Tab2Page.xaml.cs:

```
[MvxTabbedPagePresentation(TabbedPosition.Tab)]
public partial class Tab2Page : MvxContentPage<Tab2ViewModel>
```

Tab1ChildPage.xaml.cs:

```
[MvxTabbedPagePresentation(TabbedPosition.Tab)]
public partial class Tab1ChildPage : MvxContentPage<Tab1ChildViewModel>
```

I have tried changing the presentation attributes on the Tab1ChildPage.xaml.cs to this:

```
[MvxContentPagePresentation]
public partial class Tab1ChildPage : MvxContentPage<Tab1ChildViewModel>
```

and now when pressing the button I get a navigation but the tabs dissappear:

```
|-------------------------|
| <Back  Tab1Child        |
|                         |
|                         |
|                         |
|                         |
|                         |
|                         |
|                         |
|                         |
|                         |
|-------------------------|
```

---

Visual Studio 2019

Xamarin 16.9

MvvmCross v7.1.2

Comment: maybe your view presenter attribute is wrong. did you check [this page](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/platform/xamarin.forms/xamarin-forms-view-presenter?scroll=638)?

Comment: Unclear what you presentation attribute is on the view for `Tab1ChildViewModel`.

Comment: Ahh this is Xamarin.Forms. I would say, this navigation parttern is not supported out of the box and you would need to modify the presenter to get the desired behavior.